# Natural Deduction [Propositional Logic]

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I have to prove the following:

```
PREMISSES:

1. A IMPLIES ¬C
2. ¬ (B AND ¬A)
3. A OR B

CONCLUSION: ¬C
```

I've done the following so far:

```
^   AND
v   OR
¬   NEG
->  IMP


4. C              H
5. |  A           H
6. |  | ¬C        E-> 1,5
7. |  |  C        Reit 4
8. | ¬A           I¬ 5,6,7
9. |  B           H
10.|  |  B ^ ¬A   I^ 8,9
11.|  | ¬(B^¬A)   Reit 2
12.|  ¬B          I¬ 9,10,11
. . .

N. ¬C
```

I'm stuck at this point. I don't know how to continue and get an A or a B to get ¬C.

Comment: Note: you have not used premise 3 yet ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine the $\neg B$ with premise 3 to get $A$, which with premise 1 gives you $\neg C$, and thus the contradiction with $C$ you are looking for.

Comment: Isn't that kind of premise intended to be used like start with hypothesis A get to C, then hypothesis B, get to C, therefore A v B => C? Edit: I have no clue of what to use it for aside from that.

Comment: Now I recall what you are hinting. Those are the components of the Disjunctive Syllogism. Thank you, I'll try it out.

Comment: @Power_of_zero Yes! Disjunctive Syllogism! So, you want A in both cases, rather than C. The rule should be E$\lor$

Answer (score 1):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$
Always keep your mind on the goal.

You are attempting to deduce $\neg C$ using a subproof with an assumption of $C$.  The goal of this subproof is a contradiction.

The means of achieving that goal is using the third premise and $\vee$-elimination. 
$$\fitch{~~1.~A\to\neg C\\~~2.~\neg (B\wedge\neg A)\\~~3.~A\vee B}{\fitch{~~4.~C\hspace{12ex}\textsf{H}}{\fitch{~~5.~A\hspace{8.5ex}\textsf{H}}{~~6.~\neg C\hspace{7ex}{\to}\textsf{E}~1,8\\~~7.~\bot\hspace{8.5ex}\neg\textsf{E}~~4,6}\\~~8.~\neg A\hspace{11ex}\neg\textsf{I}~~5{-}7\\\fitch{~~9.~B\hspace{9.5ex}\textsf{H}}{10.~B\wedge\neg A\hspace{3ex}\wedge\textsf{I}~~8,9\\11.~\bot\hspace{9.5ex}\neg\textsf{E}~~10,2}\\12.~\bot\hspace{12ex}\vee\textsf{E}~~3,5{-}7,9{-}11}\\13.~\neg C\hspace{14ex}\neg\textsf{I}~4{-}12}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you're using classical logic, then there's a quicker proof where you immediately use $\vee$ elimination on (3), deriving $A$ in both cases.  (The case starting with $B$ requires both (2) and the double-negation law.)  Then apply (1) and you're done.

But if you want to use only intuitionistic logic (which goes nicely with natural deduction), then your approach is necessary, with Bram28's advice to finish it.